# No suitable classloader found for grab

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, classloader, junit4

I have this at the beginning of a class:

```
@Grab(group = 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module = 'tagsoup', version = '1.2')
class MyClass{...
```

I'm trying to unit test this class, but whenever I try to run JUnit 4 tests, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:198)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.chooseClassLoader(GrapeIvy.groovy:163)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$chooseClassLoader.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:153)
    at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:216)
    at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:131)
    at groovy.grape.Grape$grab.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:173)
    at ammoscanner.AmmoScanner.<clinit>(AmmoScanner.groovy)
    ... 30 more
```

Any ideas? I'm using groovy 1.7.5

Comment: What environment are you trying to run your code? IDE? Command-line?

Comment: I'm trying to run within Intelli-J.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `@Grab` makes code untestable, at least as of 01/26/2011.

Comment: Is this bug being reported anywhere?

Comment: Using `@GrabConfig( systemClassLoader=true )` makes the code untestable as of 19/03/2013.

Answer (score 6):

#### The Problem

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grape/GrapeIvy.groovy#L189-L196), this exception is thrown whenever the supplied ClassLoader's name (or it's superclasses) is not `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader` or `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader`. i.e. The target classloader must be an instance of the aforementioned classes (a bit restrictive IMHO).

#### A Solution

Currently I don't know how to configure a specific classloader using `@Grape`/`@Grab`/`@GrabConfig` annotations. The closest would be to use `@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)`, and ensure the System classloader  is an instance of one of the above ClassLoader classes.

If anyone does know, please let me know (and I'll update this answer).

#### A Workaround

The following code will programmatically download your Grapes, and load them into the supplied [GroovyClassLoader](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/lang/GroovyClassLoader.java) (admittedly, not quite what you want).

```
def loadGrapes(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = new groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader()
    Map[] grapez = [[group : 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module : 'tagsoup', version : '1.2']]
    Grape.grab(classLoader: classLoader, grapez)
    println "Class: " + classLoader.loadClass('org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.jaxp.SAXParserImpl')
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that actually seems work when calling from gradle

Answer (score 4):

Solution that worked for me (both for running tests for scripts using `@Grab` in IntelliJ and via Maven):

1. Reference the dependencies used via `@Grab` in your Maven `pom.xml` file (this is useful anyway for better coding experience):

E.g. I have the following `@Grab` in my Groovy script:

```
@Grab(group='info.picocli', module='picocli', version='4.6.1')
```

So I add the following Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>info.picocli</groupId>
      <artifactId>picocli</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. Add an optional dependency on `ivy` in your Maven `pom.xml` file (needed to handle `@Grab` properly in your IDE):

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
      <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
      <version>${ivy.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

3. In your test code, set `groovy.grape.enable` system property to `false`. **This is the main and crucial part of the solution** - it disables `@Grab` annotation processing for the script, but remember we already have those dependencies referenced in our Maven `pom.xml` file:

```
    static {
        System.setProperty("groovy.grape.enable", "false")
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        MainScript.call()
    }
```

The downside of the solution is that you have to duplicate your dependencies in `@Grab` and Maven `pom.xml` file but again, if you develop a Groovy script you oftentimes already do so to improve your coding experience (get better code highlights etc).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've tried adding

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```

like so:

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group = 'org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module = 'tagsoup', version = '1.2'),
    @GrabConfig( systemClassLoader=true )
])
class MyClass{...
```

Comment: While this did allow an Intelli-J inspection to download the library, the JUnit test still cannot run.

Comment: Furthermore, with systemClassLoader=true set, I can't run the script within in Intelli-J at all, let alone run unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using systemClassLoader=true then it seems your IDE is not rrunning the code with a groovy compiler, you can check that with a simple groovy class that outputs the class name of its classloader. I would guess it tries to compile the groovy classes and run them with a non-groovy classloader.

See also [this answer to General error during conversion: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077879/520567). Also [this blog post](http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2012/01/that-darned-no-suitable-classloader.html) explains more about running pre-compiled groovy classes with the stock classloader.

Answer (score 0):

Add the [plugin snapshot update site](http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.3/) for Kepler.

This seems to solve the "..no suitable classloader problem". Unfortunately, I still had to add the grape repo to the classpath for the project after this.

Answer (score 0):

There's one more solution for testing a class with `@Grab` annotation:

1. Extract an interface from this class.
2. Create another class which implements its interface. Move the `@Grab` annotation to this class. Then make this class a simple wrapper, which just passes all the messages to the original class.
3. Run the tests against your original class.
4. Whenever you need to have a version `@Grab`, use the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

### There is a solution to this!

You can use Groovy's metaprogramming to override the methods responsible for determining if the class loader is an instance of `groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader` or `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader`.

Because of [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7368) Groovy bug, you cannot override the private methods using metaprogramming, otherwise you could go ahead and change the `isValidTargetClassLoaderClass` method by doing this:

```
GrapeIvy.metaClass.isValidTargetClassLoaderClass = { Class loaderClass ->
    return (loaderClass != null)
}
```

However, `isValidTargetClassLoaderClass` is called by `isValidTargetClassLoader` (another private method), which is called by `chooseClassLoader`, which is a *public* method, which *can* be overridden using metaprogramming:

```
GrapeIvy.metaClass.chooseClassLoader = { Map args ->
    def loader = args.classLoader
    if (loader?.class == null) {
        loader = (args.refObject?.class
                ?: ReflectionUtils.getCallingClass(args.calleeDepth?:1)
        )?.classLoader
        while (loader && loader?.class == null) {
            loader = loader.parent
        }

        if (loader?.class == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No suitable ClassLoader found for grab")
        }
    }
    return loader
}
```

All I did was replace any calls to `!isValidTargetClassLoader` with  `loader?.class == null`.

Now, I am using Spock, so I put this code in my `setupSpec` method in my test class. However if you are using JUnit, I would imagine it would want to go in the method annotated with `@BeforeClass`.

Here is an example of it working with Spock (notice IntelliJ showing it about to return a class loader that would normally throw an exception:

[image]

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately. `GrapeIvy` has `@CompileStatic` annotation which seems to be the culrprit